# Dynamically sort a List<T> by a property

Tags: c#, .net

I know some similar questions have already been asked, but most answers rely on Linq, which I'm not interested in using here (for performance reasons).

I'm interested to see if anyone has any solutions to dynamically sort a list with a value determined at runtime. So far, I've only been able to come up with something using if-else's/switch.

Here's the sample codes I'm using to mess around and try to get this working. It's a console application, and it consists of a small model class, a Sorter class (implementing IComparer), and the Main() method:

**Project model class**

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Owner { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() 
    {
        return string.Format("--  ProjID: {0}, Title: {1}, Owner: {2}, Created on {3}", ProjID, Title, Owner, Created);
    }
}
```

**Comparer Method**

```
public class ProjectSorter : IComparer<Project>
{
    public string Prop { get; set; }

    // ctor, what do you want to sort by?
    public ProjectSorter(string prop)
    {
        Prop = prop;
    }
    public ProjectSorter() { }

    int IComparer<Project>.Compare(Project x, Project y)
    {
        if (this.Prop == "ProjID") {
            return x.ProjID.CompareTo(y.ProjID);
        }     
        else if (Prop == "Title")
        {
            return x.Title.CompareTo(y.Title);
        }
        else if (Prop == "Created")
        {
            return x.Created.CompareTo(y.Created);
        }
        // etc...

        return 0; // just to get this method working
    }
}
```

**Main method (to test the comparer/sorter)**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Project> projectList = new List<Project>
    {
        new Project { ProjID = 1, Title = "First Proj", Owner = "rushfive", Created = DateTime.Now},
        new Project { ProjID = 2, Title = "2nd Proj", Owner = "rushfive", Created = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2) },
        new Project { ProjID = 3, Title = "Amazing Redos", Owner = "waldrw", Created = DateTime.Now},
        new Project { ProjID = 4, Title = "Eat Lunch", Owner = "jedlow", Created = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5)},
        new Project { ProjID = 5, Title = "Update Labs", Owner = "somsky", Created = DateTime.Now},
    };

    Console.WriteLine("\nListing Projects in DEFAULT ORDER:");
    foreach(Project p in projectList) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(p);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\nNow, Listing Projects sorted by Title:");

    IComparer<Project> comparer1 = new ProjectSorter("Title");
    projectList.Sort(comparer1);
    foreach (Project p in projectList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(p);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\nNow, Listing Projects sorted by CREATED DATE:");

    IComparer<Project> comparer2 = new ProjectSorter("Created");
    projectList.Sort(comparer2);
    foreach (Project p in projectList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(p);
    }
}
```

Given my current implementation above, it can correctly sort a list by a property dynamically.. but by using a potentially lengthy if-else/switch logic.

Is there a better way to implement this kind of sort? A common use case for me is where a user will click on something in the browser to have a list sorted by a particular property.

It just seems like using a huge if-else/switch is maybe unnecessary, but I'm not aware of any other way (think more elegant and less code). Maybe I'm just a bit spoiled by how expressive javascript is compared to some other languages.

Any ideas on this problem?

Comment: There's no reason to avoid LINQ for performance reasons - LINQ-to-objects is basically a bunch of wrappers around traditional methods, and it probably is going to be more optimized than anything you write by hand.

Comment: Hey Joe, I'll have to look more into this. From what I've been reading, there's supposedly a performance hit because LINQ puts another complete list into memory to do sorting (correct me if I'm wrong). How can you dynamically sort a list using linq though? I understand you can easily sort by a property if you know it before it's compiled, but what if you don't know the property until runtime?

Comment: Rather than a big switch (or if/else if/else if), you can do this with reflection. Depending on how big your list is, and how much performance you need to squeeze out of it, you can also dynamically build a lambda expression, then compile it at runtime, storing the compiled lambdas in memory, and then running those would be as fast as compiled code. It's a giant pain to write, but if you want that flexibility and performance, look up "expression trees" in C#, and look for building and compiling lambda expressions.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help and recommendations!

Comment: @IsaiahLee one thing to keep in mind about the 'copy in memory' when sorting is that if you're working with reference types (which you are) then what's being duplicated in memory is just the 4 or 8 byte references (depending 32-bit or 64-bit) to the actual objects. So unless you have a huge quantity of very small objects then the performance hit for making a 'copy in memory' is minimal.

Comment: I would try using Linq. If it has the performance problems that you're concerned about, then I'd look into alternative methods. Linq is heavily used in the community, and has been heavily tested. Don't reinvent the wheel, if the wheel works just fine. Especially when the person,who has to fix a bug in your code later down the road, has to re-reinvent the wheel to fix a problem.

Comment: Just to add, exposing the underlying list / data source as a method that takes a LINQ expression and returns an `IQueryable<T>` makes your life immeasurably easier. We had a method that took the expression, added some business logic to it (`... AND DeletedFlag = false`) and returned the results. Later on, we were able to swap the implementation out so the result was lazy loaded giving us tons of flexibility and saving on performance where not required (in the latter case instance, data was being loaded via WCF from another machine so the benefit was significant)

Answer (score 1):

I would make a wrapper that accepts a lambda to perform the transformation from `Project` to compared object.

Note that this assumes that all the involved types implement `IComparable<T>`.

```
public static class SortProject
{
    public static ProjectSorter<T> By<T>(Func<Project, T> transform)
    {
        return new ProjectSorter<T>(transform);
    }
}

public class ProjectSorter<T> : IComparer<Project>
                  where T : IComparable<T>
{
    private Func<Project, T> _transform;

    public ProjectSorter(Func<Project, T> transform)
    {
        _transform = transform;
    }

    public int Compare(Project left, Project right)
    {
        //Put null first in order, note that this can be changed based on what you want
        if (left == null) return right == null ? -1 : 0;
        if (right == null) return 1;

        return _transform(left).CompareTo(_transform(right));
    }
}
```

I think with the static method C# can deduce the correct thing here (didn't test, explicit annotations will work).

For instance:

```
projectList.Sort(SortProject.By(p => p.Title));
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve the `"Title"` means `p => p.Title` problem, but I wasn't certain if that was core to your underlying issue or not.

Answer (score 1):

`<rant>`First of all, not sorting through Linq because of performance reasons, I don't believe that it will make a difference. Please show where Linq is causing a performance hit, memory pressure or anything like that in your application, I would be deeply surprised.
`</rant>`

So, let's say we want a generic sorting approach where we supply a property name. If we could supply an expression instead, it would be much easier:

```
class PropertyComparer<T> : IComparer<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T, IComparable> _selector;

    public PropertyComparer(Func<T, IComparable> selector)
    {
        this._selector = selector;
    }

    public int Compare(T x, T y)
    {
        var left = this._selector(x);
        var right = this._selector(y);
        if (left == null)
        {
            if (right == null)
                return 0;
            else
                return -right.CompareTo(null);
        }
        else
        {
            return left.CompareTo(right);
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise, we have to build one:

```
class PropertyComparer<T> : IComparer<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T, IComparable> _selector;

    public PropertyComparer(string propertyName)
    {
        var selectorParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof (T), "x"); //parameter [T x]
        var property = Expression.PropertyOrField(selectorParameter, propertyName); // [x.Property]
        var cast = Expression.Convert(property, typeof(IComparable)); // [x.Property as IComparable]
        this._selector = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, IComparable>>(cast, selectorParameter).Compile();
    }

    public int Compare(T x, T y)
    {
        var left = this._selector(x);
        var right = this._selector(y);
        if (left == null)
        {
            if (right == null)
                return 0;
            else
                return -right.CompareTo(null);
        }
        else
        {
            return left.CompareTo(right);
        }
    }
}
```

It assumes the property is `IComparable` so that it can do sorting.

Comment: nice sample of expression tree use for dynamic linq. maybe add a sample Usage to answer to show how sort can be called.

Comment: @philsoady You just construct the comparer (`var comp = new PropertyComparer<Project>("Title");`), the usage is the same as in the question, that's why I didn't leave any examples.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a generic comparer like that :

```
/// <summary>
/// Generic comparer by key selector
/// </summary>
public class KeySelectorComparer<T, TProperty> : Comparer<T> where TProperty : IComparable<TProperty>
{
    private readonly Func<T, TProperty> keySelector;
    public KeySelectorComparer(Func<T, TProperty> keySelector)
    {
        if (keySelector == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("'keySelector' parameter can not be null.", "keySelector");

        this.keySelector = keySelector;
    }
    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null) || ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;

        return this.keySelector(x).Equals(this.keySelector(y));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(obj, null)) return 0;

        return this.keySelector(obj).GetHashCode();
    }

    public override int Compare(T x, T y)
    {
        if (x == null)
        {
            if (y == null)
                return 0;

            return 1;
        }
        if (y == null)
            return -1;

        return this.keySelector(x).CompareTo(this.keySelector(y));
    }
}
```

and so you can compare any collections you want based on the keyselector you want like that:

```
var list = new List<MyObj>();
list.Sort(new KeySelectorComparer<MyObj, int>(s=> s.Id));
```